# Highcharts Stacked bar chart with db value (Dynamic Data)

Tags: c#, highcharts

I need stacked bar chart with db value. So values are dynamic. Here's my scenario, 
there are plenty of users in the system but only 2 users are active till now. peter used task1 and task3 and sam used the task1,task2 and task3. Each task has open,pending,cancel status .So for Peter i want to display 2 stacked bars with the status and for same its 3 stacked bars. I couldn't achieve this in highcharts. Picture representation given below.

```
 $(function () {
                 $('#container').highcharts({
                     chart: {
                         type: 'column'
                     },
                     title: {
                         x: 0,
                         text: null,
                         style: {
                             fontSize: '13px',
                             fontWeight: 'Bold',
                         }
                     },

                     credits: {
                         enabled: false
                     },

                     xAxis: {
                         categories: [
                            'Sam','Peter',
                        ],
                        crosshair: true
                    },
                    yAxis: [{
                        min: 0,allowDecimals: false,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Opportunities'
                        }
                    }],
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b> {point.key}</b><br>',//{series.options.stack} :
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y} / {point.stackTotal}'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        depth: 40
                    }
                },
                series: [
               {name:'task1',data:[1], stack:'Sam'},
               {name:'task1',data:[1], stack:'Peter'},              {name:'task2',data:[0], stack:'Peter'},
                {name:'task3',data:[1], stack:'Sam'},{name:'task3',data:[0], stack:'Peter'}]

            });
        });
```

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtAccMgrs.Rows.Count; i++)
               {
                   string accMgr = dtAccMgrs.Rows[i]["AccMgr"].ToString();
                   AccMgrList += "'" + accMgr + "',";
                   dtData = dtOppr.Select("AccMgr='" + accMgr + "'");
                   AccMgrDataOpen += "{name:'Open',data:[";
                   AccMgrDataPending += "{name:'Pending',data:[";
                   AccMgrDataCancelled += "{name:'Cancelled',data:[";

                   for (int j = 0; j < dtData.Length; j++)
                   {
                       AccMgrDataOpen += dtData[j]["Oppr_Open"];
                       AccMgrDataPending += dtData[j]["Oppr_Pending"];
                       AccMgrDataCancelled += dtData[j]["Oppr_Cancelled"];
                       string open = dtData[j]["Oppr_Open"].ToString();
                       int OpprTotal = Int32.Parse(open) + Int32.Parse(dtData[j]["Oppr_Pending"].ToString()) + Int32.Parse(dtData[j]["Oppr_Cancelled"].ToString());

                   }
                   AccMgrDataOpen += "], stack:'" + accMgr + "'},";
                   AccMgrDataPending += "], stack:'" + accMgr + "'},";
                   AccMgrDataCancelled += "], stack:'" + accMgr + "'},";
               }
               AccMgrDataOpen += "]"; AccMgrDataPending += "]"; AccMgrDataCancelled += "]"; AccMgrList += "]";
               AccMgrDataOpen = AccMgrDataOpen.Replace(",]", "]");
               AccMgrDataPending = AccMgrDataPending.Replace(",]", "]");
               AccMgrDataCancelled = AccMgrDataCancelled.Replace(",]", "]");
```

Comment: Can you add json data from db in post or use http://myjson.com/ to create live example

Comment: im passing my data as per in my code,i didnt get how to pass the data for dynamic multi bar(task) with stacked(status). im bit confusing to merge 2 types in a single json data. that's y i gave pictorial representation.

Comment: Actually Im passing the data from server side, please refer the code above, i ve added that.

Comment: @Deep3015 any idea please

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce the issue. Try to make live example to show the issue

Comment: Let me try to explain,Tasks and status are random and based on the managers. Managers list also random. All are from database.Tasks are a separate bars. statuses are in stacked column, based on the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of tricky thing to do in Highcharts.

One way of making it work is to process your data so that it looks like this:

```
  series: [
    // Task 1
    {
      name: 'Task 1',
      id: 'task1',
      stack: 'Task 1 Peter',
      pointPlacement: -0.1,
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        status: 'O'
      }, {
        x: 0,
        status: 'C'
      }]
    }, {
      linkedTo: 'task1',
      stack: 'Task 1 Sam',
      pointPlacement: -0.2,
      data: [{
        x: 1,
        status: 'O'
      }, {
        x: 1,
        status: 'P'
      }, {
        x: 1,
        status: 'C'
      }]
    },
    // Task 2
    {
      name: 'Task 2',
      id: 'task2',
      stack: 'Task 2 Sam',
      data: [{
        x: 1,
        status: 'P'
      }, {
        x: 1,
        status: 'C'
      }]
    },
 (...)
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/2rbpp7wq/

Every column is a separate series. Series that are the same task are linked together (`linkedTo`). `pointPlacement` is used to position them properly (these values should depend on the number of columns in one category and should be computed automatically).

`stackLabes` need to be positioned manually like this:

```
  render: function() {

    var series = this.series,
        yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
      stacks = yAxis.stacks;

    for (var key in stacks) {
      var stack = stacks[key];
                series.forEach(function(s) {
        var stack_;
        for(var key_ in stack) {        
            stack_ = stack[key_];
        }

        if(s.stackKey.substring(6) === stack_.stack) {
            stack_.label.attr({
            x: s.points[0].plotX
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: @ Kamil Kulig,thank you so much :) i couldn't get how to use the pointPlacement,others can understand. Any other option available for pointPlacement. because as i mentioned im getting values from db.

Comment: is there anyway to assign "stack" name to the x axis instead of  using pointplacement?

Comment: `pointPlacement` (notice that `grouping` is disabled) only changes the position of the column (moves it horizontally). What do you mean by saying *"assing 'stack' name to the x axis"*?